# Colocate docker containers using docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, orchestration

I have two services (serviceA and serviceB). ServiceA is a java application and serviceB is a cache. I would like to always scale these services together (one replica of each on a particular host) and to configure them so that they always communicate with the component on the same host (serviceA to communicate with serviceB from the same host) not using docker swarm DNS.

Initially I have created two service in docker compose and used network aliases, but this does not ensure colocation and communication between components on the same host.

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  serviceA:
    ...
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    network:
      testnetwork:
        aliases: ["serviceA"]

    serviceB:
      ...
      deploy:
        replicas: 3
      network:
        testnetwork:
          aliases: ["serviceB"]

networks:
  testnetwork:
    driver: overlay
```